# Integrating $f(x)=\int|\cos(x)|dx$ and then solving $f(x)=\frac {2x}{\pi}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, recreational-mathematics, absolute-value

I realised the other day that by applying absolute value signs to the cosine function and then integrating, I would get an almost sine function that doesn't have negative slope.

And then I also noticed that it would probably stay close to the line $$g(x)=\frac {2x}{\pi}$$

So could someone integrate $$f(x)=\int|\cos(x)|dx,$$
then set it equal to $g(x)$ and solve?

Comment: There are no functions that can describe the integral of $|\cos(x)|$

Comment: Aw, dang it.  The graph was pretty cool though. @VarunIyer

Comment: $|cos(x)|$ actually has infinitely many indefinite integrals, since it's a continuous function, and one antiderivative $F(x)$ can be used to produce others by taking $F(x)+c$ for $c$ constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral (from $0$) may be represented in form

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\left( \sin(x)\operatorname{sgn}(\cos(x))+
\sum _{n=1}^N\left(2\operatorname{H}\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}+n\pi\right)-2\right)+
\sum _{n=0}^{N-1}2\operatorname{H}\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}-n\pi\right)\right)$$

Where $\operatorname{H}$ is the [Heaviside step function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html). You can see the plot [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wrxq0acwcu). It is close to the line $y=2x/\pi$ and the functions are equal at points $$\left(\frac{k\pi }{2},k\right),\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: The only problem with this is that it goes down at some points.  We can note that $f'(x)>0$, therefore the graph never goes down.  The shape of the graph is also noted to be equivalent to sine between $-\frac{\pi}2\le x\le\frac{\pi}2$

Comment: @SimpleArt my graph doesn't go down (remember to move the slider $N$, as $N\to\infty$)

Comment: This is not the right answer. He is solving $f(x)=\frac{2x}{\pi}$, the original problem asked for the solutions of $f(x)=\frac{x}{\pi}$. That $2$ makes a big difference.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio My bad.  I meant to have a $2$ there.  Sorry if I caused much pain.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio the original problem more likely asked for solutions of $f=g$ where $g$ is a line function close to $f$, whereas $x/\pi$ is not so close to $f$

Answer (score 3):

Consider that $\left|\,\cos(x)\,\right|$ has a not-so-terrible Fourier cosine series. In particular:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \left|\,\cos(x)\,\right| &=& \frac{2}{\pi}+\frac{4}{3\pi}\cos(2x)-\frac{4}{15\pi}\cos(2x)+\frac{4}{35\pi}\cos(4x)-\ldots\\&=&\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{4n^2-1}\,\cos(2n x)\tag{1}\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence $\int_{0}^{z}\left|\,\cos(x)\,\right|dx$ *can* be written as a fast-converging series:
$$\int_{0}^{z}\left|\,\cos(x)\,\right|dx = \frac{2z}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)(2n)(2n+1)}\sin(2nz)\tag{2} $$
and the difference between the LHS and $\frac{2z}{\pi}$, in absolute value, is obviously bounded by:
$$ \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n)(2n+1)}=\frac{2}{\pi}\left(\log 4-1\right)<\frac{1}{4}.\tag{3}$$
That gives that the only solutions of $\int_{0}^{z}\left|\,\cos(x)\,\right|dz = \frac{z}{\pi}$ have to lie quite close to the origin, for sure in the region $|z|<\frac{\pi}{2}$. In such a case, however, the absolute value appearing inside the integral is completely useless, we are just solving $\sin(z)=\frac{z}{\pi}$, with the only solution $z=0$ inside the given domain.

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion "have to lie quite close to the origin"? There are plenty of other solutions; see the answer by 
kamil09875.

Comment: @HansLundmark: plenty of other solutions? I do not agree. Our function, $\int_{0}^{z}|\cos(x)|\,dx$, is between $\frac{2z}{\pi}-\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{2z}{\pi}+\frac{1}{4}$, hence it cannot equal $\frac{z}{\pi}$ if $|z|$ is too large.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Have you even checked kamil09875's answer?

Comment: @SimpleArt: he is equating $\int_{0}^{z}|\cos(x)|\,dx$ and $\frac{\color{red}{2}z}{\pi}$, but the original problem is different, it asks for the solutions of $\int_{0}^{z}|\cos(x)|\,dx=\frac{\color{red}{1}z}{\pi}$.

Comment: Actually, I can't see what's wrong with it.  He took an indefinite integral, first of all, and did it for all $x$.  Yours only tells me what happens in that small range.  I do respect that your definite is equivalent to my indefinite integral though.

Comment: @SimpleArt: the issue is not in the primitive, the issue is that we are solving two different equations with that primitive.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice the missing factor of 2! Anyway, it was apparently supposed to have been there...

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\int\left|\cos(x)\right|\space\text{d}x=\sin(x)\text{sgn}(\cos(x))+\text{C}$$

Comment: This is not true, your integral is not continuous

Comment: Thank you for trying though.